# Typescript -> a dynamic response from an API how to type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am consuming an api that returns nested json. It is dynamic so the keys will often be different, but can only be an object or a string, cannot be an array or number etc.

Here is an example:

```
const response = {
  name: 'Pete',
  location: 'London',
  age: {
    year: '21'
  }
}
```

I have tried type it like this:

```
type Response = {
    [key: string]: string
}
```

Then in a React component I want to use it like this:

```
type Response = {
    [key: string]: string
}

const Foo = ({ data }: Response) => {
   return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Property 'x' does not exist on type 'string'

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

here is a link to stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4n7vcy?file=App.tsx

Comment: You said key and value is guaranteed to be a string but in your example, age is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is assigning the type `Response` to the props argument of your `Foo` functional component. So actually, the `Foo` component accepts a props object with the type of `Response`, but the `data` variable is inferred as a string by typescript. What you should do instead is;

```
interface IFooProps{
  data: Response;
}

const Foo = (props: IFooProps) => {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.data, null, 2)}</pre>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the values in your type are strings. When you extracted the `data` key its type was a string. You either need to type it like:

```
type Response = {
  data: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
}
```

Or accept it in the component like

```
const Foo = (data: Response) => {
  // ...
}
```

If you want the values to be either string or nested objects, you can do:

```
type Response = {
  [key: string]: string | Response
}
```

And then the `data` in your example will be of type `string | Response`.